# Android Studio BumbleeBee Freeze when gradle is building

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

since i updated to bumblebee android studio suddenly freezes when i want to build/run the app. it freezes while gradle is building the project.

nothing shows up in Event Viewer and android studio doesnt displays a message about any IDE error

and im not sure where to find the logs for the android studio IDE maybe i can get a hint about the problem there

Comment: I'm having the same problem. AS Bumblebee also randomly freezes when Jetpack Compose previews are rendered. This is on macOS 12.2.1. Did you find a solution?

Comment: nope not yet, maybe wait for a patch or update i guess btw im on windows 10